# Array elements changing values if I comment out cout statement. Is this memory leak related?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-leaks

I'm working on a KNN algorithm with 2D arrays. It worked great when I first had the nodes be simple X and Y coordinates, but when I changed it to 2D arrays and reworked some things, I run into a funny issue.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

//A node
struct Node
{
    int groupValue;
    int col = 16; //We only have to update these to reflect the bitmap dimensions
    int row = 16;
    int bitmap[16][16];
    float distance = -1;
    //distance is the distance this node is from another

    //Overloading this operator to make swapping them with insertion sort easier
    Node& operator =(const Node& n)
    {
        for(int a = 0; a < row; a++)
        {
            for(int b = 0; b < col; b++)
            {
                bitmap[a][b] = n.bitmap[a][b];
            }
        }
        distance = n.distance;
        groupValue = n.groupValue;
        return *this;
    }
};

void printNode(Node n)
{
    for(int a = 0; a < 16; a++)
    {
        for(int b = 0; b < 16; b++)
            cout << n.bitmap[a][b] << ".";
        cout << endl;
    }
}

struct Group
{
    int frequency = 0;
    int id;
};

void insertionSort(Node arr[], int n)
{
    int i, key, j;
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        key = arr[i].distance;
        j = i - 1;

        while (j >= 0 && arr[j].distance > key)
        {
            Node temp = arr[j+1];
            arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = temp;
            j = j - 1;
        }
        arr[j + 1].distance = key;
    }
}

//Takes two bitmaps and find the distance between each pixel
//using the formula d=sqrt(sum((pixel_1-pixel_2)^2))
float bitmapDistance(Node n1, Node n2)
{
    Node differences; //Node's bitmap data will be the differences
                        //squared of each pixel from n1 and n2.
    float diff;
    for(int a = 0; a < n1.row; a++)
    {
        for(int b = 0; b < n1.col; b++)
        {
            diff = n1.bitmap[a][b] - n2.bitmap[a][b];
            differences.bitmap[a][b] = diff * diff; //Squared difference
        }
    }

    //Now we need to sum up the squared differences that we stored earlier
    float sum;
    for(int a = 0; a < n1.row; a++)
    {
        for(int b = 0; b < n1.col; b++)
        {
            sum += differences.bitmap[a][b];
        }
    }

    //Now just take the square root of the sum and return it
    if(sum < 0.01) //To fix some weird rounding issues I added this. 0.01 is arbitrary.
        return 0;
    return sqrt(sum);
}

/*
 *Classify the node using KNN algorithm
 *Multiple groups can be used, and we count how many neighbors
 *belong to each group.
 *n is the total amount of nodes
 *k is the number of nearby neighbors
*/
int classify(Node arr[], int n, int k, Node node)
{
    //Two switches for sampling, recorded as binary (0-3)
    Group g0;
    g0.id = 0;
    Group g1;
    g1.id = 1;
    Group g2;
    g2.id = 2;
    Group g3;
    g3.id = 3;
    Group groupFrequency[4] = {g0, g1, g2, g3};

    //For each neighbor of the given node (node) we use the distance formula
    //and set it's distance member variable to this measurement
    for(int a = 0; a < n; a++)
    {
        arr[a].distance = bitmapDistance(node, arr[a]);
        //cout << arr[a].distance << ","; //<===============PROBLEM AREA===============
    }
    cout << endl << "----------" << endl;
    insertionSort(arr, n-1);
    for(int a = 0; a < n; a++)
        cout << arr[a].distance << ",";
    cout << endl << "----------" << endl;
    //Look at all the nearest neighbors and see which group they belong to
    //Increase a counter for each group the neighbor belongs to
    for(int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        if(arr[i].groupValue == 0)
            groupFrequency[0].frequency++;
        else if(arr[i].groupValue == 1)
            groupFrequency[1].frequency++;
        else if(arr[i].groupValue == 2)
            groupFrequency[2].frequency++;
        else if(arr[i].groupValue == 3)
            groupFrequency[3].frequency++;
    }

    cout << "Neighboring group frequencies:" << endl;
    cout << "Group Zero: " << groupFrequency[0].frequency << endl;
    cout << "Group One: " << groupFrequency[1].frequency << endl;
    cout << "Group Two: " << groupFrequency[2].frequency << endl;
    cout << "Group Three: " << groupFrequency[3].frequency << endl;
    cout << "-------------------------------------------------" << endl;

    //Now we just need to look at the most common frequency and classify our node
    int highestFrequency = 0;
    int groupNumber = -1; //If -1 is returned, something went wrong.
    for(int a = 0; a < 4; a++)
    {
        if(groupFrequency[a].frequency >= highestFrequency)
        {
            highestFrequency = groupFrequency[a].frequency;
            groupNumber = groupFrequency[a].id;
        }
    }

    return groupNumber;
}

//This stuff is just setup for testing purposes. Could this be the issue's origin?
int main()
{
    Node nodeArray[200];
    for(int c = 0; c < 100; c++)
    {
        for(int a = 0; a < 16; a++)
        {
            for(int b = 0; b < 16; b++)
            {
                nodeArray[c].groupValue = 0;
                nodeArray[c].bitmap[a][b] = rand()%10;
            }
        }
    }
    for(int c = 100; c < 200; c++)
    {
        for(int a = 0; a < 16; a++)
        {
            for(int b = 0; b < 16; b++)
            {
                nodeArray[c].groupValue = 1;
                nodeArray[c].bitmap[a][b] = 50;//rand()%10+50;
            }
        }
    }
    Node testNode;
    for(int a = 0; a < 16; a++)
    {
        for(int b = 0; b < 16; b++)
        {
            testNode.bitmap[a][b] = 50;//rand()%10+50;
        }
    }

    int num = classify(nodeArray, 200, 189, testNode);
    cout << "Test node has a group classification of: " << num << endl << endl;

    printNode(testNode);
    cout << endl << "last node in array:" << endl;
    printNode(nodeArray[199]);
    cout << endl << bitmapDistance(testNode, nodeArray[199]) << endl << "first node in array:" << endl;
    printNode(nodeArray[0]);
    cout << bitmapDistance(testNode, nodeArray[0]);
}
```

The problem specifically is on line 124, in the `classify()` function in the for loop

```
for(int a = 0; a < n; a++)
{
    arr[a].distance = bitmapDistance(node, arr[a]);
    //cout << arr[a].distance << ","; //<====PROBLEM AREA
}
```

This loop is responsible for calculating the distance each node is from the sample/test node. The "arr" array is then sorted a couple of lines later via insertion sort.

If I have the `for` loop print out the distance values, everything works perfectly fine. I can see that all the data is properly there.

However, if I comment it out, and only print the sorted data, everything is wrong (the data does not mess up if I comment out the print statements for the sorted data, strangely enough. It's just this one line that breaks everything).

I have attached images depicting the differences between the commented line (wrong) and the uncommented line (correct) running to better show what issues I'm dealing with.

***Basically, the data will lose decimal precision, have seemingly random values, and any zero value will be non-existent if I comment out this specific line.***

(I know the `K` value should be low, but I'm using high numbers for testing right now)

**Some of the output when I *don't* comment out the line**

[image]

**Some of the output when I *do* comment out the line**

[image]

As you can see, when I comment out the line, all the sorted distance values become garbage.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: `bitmapDistance` exhibits undefined behavior by way of accessing uninitialized variable `sum`

Comment: `float sum;` should be `float sum = 0.;` At least that  code invokes UB without it

Comment: On a side note: `int col` and `int row` should be `const` since `bitmap[][]` can't change size. And the manual `operator=` is unnecessary since the compiler-generated `operator=` should suffice. And `printNode()`, `bitmapDistance()`, and `classify()` should be passing their `Node` parameter by `const` reference.

Comment: There is no problem. First you printed distances along with the calculation(When you uncommented the problem area). Then you sorted the distances and printed. Therefore the outputs are different.

Comment: @mmj The outputs should not be different. The problem is that the distances are garbage values ONLY when I comment out that line. If I keep that line around, the distances will be proper when sorted.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I added those changes, and it worked! I'm not sure why, but thank you! I still have an issue with the sorted distances losing any decimal precision, but I think I can live with that.